# Programmatically change solid color in an existing shape

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have a circular view with a customized border, implemented using [CircularImageView](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) library and inflated in a `RecyclerView`. So far I've put an image in it, but now I want to replace it with a single-colored round and a text upon it.

I created the following shape (`shape_colored_circle.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <size
        android:height="70dp"
        android:width="70dp"/>
    <solid
        android:color="#00f"/>
</shape>
```

And added a `TextView` together with the `CircularImageView` in a `FrameLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            app:civ_border="true"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/border_color"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:civ_shadow="true"
            app:civ_shadow_color="@color/grey"
            app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
            android:contentDescription="@string/card_thumbnail"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm aware that the layout seems a bit odd ("why is the top `LinearLayout` necessary?"), but without it the view simply does not appear in the `RecyclerView` whereas this layout (which is taken from the library's example) serves our needs.

In `onBindViewHolder` I set the shape as the `CircularImageView` resource:

```
holder.thumbnail.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_colored_circle));
```

And finally I see what I was expecting. The problem is that my drawable have a specific color set in advance. Therefore, I tried to create a shape programmatically:

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
gd.setColor(colors[position]);             //Getting the color from a predefined array of colors
holder.thumbnail.setImageDrawable(gd);
```

But the view just turns into a black rectangle. I tried a few more solutions for creating a shape programmatically (all of them are pretty similar) to no avail - I either see a black rectangle or nothing at all.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to create a shape, or some way to change the existing one at runtime? Or maybe a totally different way to achieve the required behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: A few years ago I ran into an issue where the background of my drawable was turning black when I tried to set the color programmatically.  Maybe a similar problem?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581900/android-button-background-xml-sometimes-loses-alpha-when-setting-color-filter

Comment: @0x5453 I added `gd.setAlpha()`. For value 255 it's a black rectangle, for value 0 it's (obviously) invisible. Do you thing that your solution is relevant for programmatically created drawables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Vijay Pal Vishwakarma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5069742/vijay-pal-vishwakarma) I managed to solve the case.

First, I set the predefined shape as the source of the `CircularImageView`:

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/shape_colored_circle"      //Note this line
            app:civ_border="true"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/border_color"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:civ_shadow="true"
            app:civ_shadow_color="@color/grey"
            app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
            android:contentDescription="@string/card_followee_large_thumbnail"/>
```

Then, in `onBindViewHolder` I get the existing drawable and change its color:

```
GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) holder.thumbnail.getDrawable();
if (gd != null) {
    gd.setColor(colors[position]);
}
```

Comment: this is an exact copy of my approach, isn't it?

Comment: No, here `shape_colored_circle` is used as the source and not as a background.

Answer (score 3):

```
   <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/card_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_colored_circle" //Note
    android:contentDescription="@string/card_thumbnail"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    app:civ_border="true"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/border_color"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_shadow="true"
    app:civ_shadow_color="@color/grey"
    app:civ_shadow_radius="10"/>`

GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) holder.thumbnail.getBackground()
if (gd != null) {
  gd.mutate();
  gd.setColor(colors[position]);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `CircularImageView` background is the whole rectangle behind the circle. Therefore I must set the source and not the background.